# how can i call my two functions intro my main function?

Tags: c++

so the first function will multiply the input by pi and make it inside cos, and the second function will multiply the same input by pi and make it inside sin. then in the int main, I created a for loop, in order to store the value from the user and then i will cal my two function to do the rest, but it gives me error , i don't know why
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 
double xpicos(double x)
{//const double pi = 3.14159265;

double xpicos = cos(x*pi);
 return xpicos; 
 }  

   double xpisin(double x)
   {const double pi = 3.14159265;
   double xpisin = sin(x*pi);

       return xpisin; 
   }

int mian ()
{
   const double pi = 3.14159265;
double x=0;
double y = 0;
    const int capacity = 200;
    double corners[capacity];
    cout << "enter" ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {cin >> corners[i];
    double x = xpicos(corners[i]); 
    double y =xpisin(corners[i]);

    }
  cout << x << "," << y ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SciComp!. This question is poorly formatted and is not really about computational science. I have submitted an edit to try and improve it, but I suspect that this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am including this answer to help you (despite the fact I suspect this question will be closed). Your code has some obvious mistakes (you spelt main wrong....). Here is what it should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 
double xpicos(double x)
{
  const double pi = 3.14159265;
  return cos(x*pi);
}  

double xpisin(double x)
{
  const double pi = 3.14159265;
  return sin(x*pi); 
}

int main ()
{
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
  const int capacity = 200;
  double corners[capacity];

  cout << "enter: " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    cin >> corners[i];
    x = xpicos(corners[i]); 
    y = xpisin(corners[i]);
  }
  cout << x << "," << y << endl;  //you can move this inside the for loop
                                  //if that is what you want

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of errors and mistakes in your code.  You don't need `iomanip`, `main` is spelt `mian`, `pi` isn't in the correct scope, you re-declare `x` and `y` and your `cout` fell out of it's `for` loop and probably wants a `'\n'` after each line.  So something more like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double pi = 3.14159265;

double xpicos(double x)
{
    double xpicos = cos(x*pi);
    return xpicos;
}

double xpisin(double x)
{
    double xpisin = sin(x*pi);
    return xpisin;
}

int main ()
{
    const int capacity = 200;
    double corners[capacity];

    cout << "Enter: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        cin >> corners[i];
        double x = xpicos(corners[i]);
        double y = xpisin(corners[i]);
        cout << x << ", " << y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the picture for it. it gives weird errors 
[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Please place this image in the body of your question.  It really doesn't belong in the *answer* section.